# Setup dynamic api keys for rails geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to implement a general 'application settings' page for my application. on this page I want my customers to be able to put their own google api key for the rails geocoder gem. I have read through the documentation but could not find any way to set this api key in a dynamic way (through a form).

Is there any way to do this dynamically so the client can use his own google api key?

Small note, every application will only have 1 api key, but I'm trying to do this dynamically so I won't have to think about it anymore down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Geocode.configure`:

```
Geocoder.configure(
     :timeout  => 5,
     :lookup   => :yandex,
     :api_key  => "2a9fsa983jaslfj982fjasd",
     :units    => :km
)
```

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/e45f8bd3173c28e03efbfaf03eab7c5afaf4621a/lib/geocoder/configuration.rb#L7

Comment: Maybe you would want to combine this with as `before_action` callback, with something like `Geocoder.configure(api_key: current_user.geocoder_api_key)`.

Comment: Ahaa! I was under the impression that this could only be used in an initializer file for some reason. This works for me, thanks!